# Ways to prevent underfitting and overfitting to when using data augmentation to train a transposed CNN

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, overfitting-underfitting

I'm training a CNN (one using a series of `ConvTranspose2D` in `pytorch`) that uses input data from JSON to constitute an image. Unlike natural language, the input data can be in any order, as it contains info about various sprites in a scene.

In my first attempts to train the model, I didn't change the order of the input data (meaning, on each epoch, each sprite was represented in the same place in the input data). The model learned for about 10 epochs, but then there started to be divergence between the training loss (which continued to go down) and the test loss. So classic overfitting.

I tried to solve this by doing a form of data augmentation where the output data (in this case an image) stayed the same but I shuffled the order of the input data. As I have around 400 sprites, the maximum shuffling is `400!`, so theoretically this can vastly expand the amount of training data. For example, instead of 100k JSON documents corresponding to 100K images, by shuffling the order of sprites in the input data, you have `400!*100000` training data points. In practice of course this amount of data is impractical, so I went with around 2m data points for an initial test. The issue I ran into here was that the model was not learning at all - after getting to a certain loss very quickly (after the first few mini-batches), it didn't learn at all for around 4 epochs. So classic underfitting.

Like Goldilocks, I'd like to find "just right" between the initial overfitting and subsequent underfitting. I'm wondering other strategies I could try out. One idea I had was letting the model train on a predetermined order of sprites (the overfitting case) and then, once overfitting starts (ie two straight epochs with divergence between the test and training loss) shuffling the data. I can also play with changing the model, although it can only be so big because of constraints with the hardware and the fact that inference needs to happen in under 20ms.

Are there any papers or techniques that are recommended in this scenario where data augmentation can lead to vastly more data points but results in a model ceasing to learn? Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Could you please clarify what kind of data augmentation you used? It seems to me that shuffling is not an appropriate augmentation.

Comment: Shuffling is what I meant by "data augmentation", as the order of the input data to produce the output does not matter, so by using the input in different permutations you can (theoretically) get more data. Am I right, then, that this shuffling will not help the model learn?

Comment: We typically don't call shuffling a data augmentation, unless your data is a special type, e.g., some time-series data, but I couldn't tell it from your description. Considering a model f in your problem, f that observes x_i, i.e., the predictions f(x_i), is not affected by the order of x_i.

Comment: You may like to try flipping, cropping, rotation, etc, to augment your data such that f(x_i)=f(A(x_i))=y, where A means the augmentation operations.

Comment: Shuffling isn't really going to improve performance, you should look at what hpwww suggests, as well as play around with different hyperparameter settings, dropout, and/or regularisation.